# how to use os.listdir() in smartsheet?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I would like to get all the folder that are in a specific folder in smartsheet

I wanted to use os.listdir but I am not sure on how to use it on smartsheet
any idea ?

any idea on how to implement that without os.listdir ?

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of objects within a specified Smartsheet folder, you'll need to use the Smartsheet API -- specifically the [Get Folder](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#operation/get-folder) operation.

To issue a **GET Folder** request, you'll need to know the ID of the folder that you want to get. The easiest way to determine a folder's ID is by (manually) logging into Smartsheet, navigating to the location where the folder resides, then right click on the folder name and choose **Properties**. The following screenshot shows where you'll find the folder's ID in the **Properties** dialog window.

[image: Smartsheet Folder Properties dialog window]

To retrieve the contents of this folder, the **GET Folder** API request would be:

`GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/folders/1589169626605444`

The response will specify the folder properties, including collections of objects that the folder contains such as `sheets`, `folders`, `reports`, `sights`, etc. Note that the response will only contain the items that exist at the top-level of the specified folder -- i.e., it won't contain any items that exist within subfolders of that folder.

For example, let's say the folder I want to get the contents of contains the following items (2 folders, 2 dashboards (sights), 2 reports, and 2 sheets).

[image: Smartsheet folder contents]

The **GET Folder** response for the parent folder shown in the screenshot above is:

```
{
    "id": 1589169626605444,
    "name": "Parent Folder",
    "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/folders/XvFv8qxCG5R3VqmCX5CG5PxC6PRp9C336Hj2mwv1",
    "sheets": [
        {
            "id": 8573752976926596,
            "name": "Sheet 1",
            "accessLevel": "OWNER",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/sheets/6CcCwJhJPRCGGR536F7wQ8QR8G5Rwwp2v69wP831",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:26Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:26Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3942867698771844,
            "name": "Sheet 2",
            "accessLevel": "OWNER",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/sheets/r8j3PRx33gfH2rvmw77QWQ4GH64Vx73cjH794xw1",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:31Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:31Z"
        }
    ],
    "folders": [
        {
            "id": 304940045363076,
            "name": "Subfolder 1",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/folders/HQhfCrwwrcj858qxCjf8j3gV43R97gp2CQjqv6q1"
        },
        {
            "id": 797521254606724,
            "name": "Subfolder 2",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/folders/M8fpH7wcJmHrWr7RQV7pqr5xWfcqCcjjRvjfMX81"
        }
    ],
    "reports": [
        {
            "id": 3321248492087172,
            "name": "Report 1",
            "accessLevel": "OWNER",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/reports/7v96G7r9Q7GJXq8R7Xg9pFCRM83MvmhHVW7RqXV1",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:12Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:12Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 7235389627885444,
            "name": "Report 2",
            "accessLevel": "OWNER",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/reports/hGP5pFVhW65QC3whQW9p8HQ75HmWRXFrHm9F4MW1",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:20Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:20Z"
        }
    ],
    "sights": [
        {
            "id": 8871794707851140,
            "name": "Dashboard 1",
            "accessLevel": "OWNER",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/dashboards/fccJ8V54x3jhPr2gxxC96C2rVjV72fH9wCJWvp81",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:48Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:48Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2327501499328388,
            "name": "Dashboard 2",
            "accessLevel": "OWNER",
            "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/dashboards/X8VmpVvWPhHHfPPFWhGMcJpPXJvPPMg6FWwpwhX1",
            "createdAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:58Z",
            "modifiedAt": "2022-09-07T21:09:58Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

(This is just an example. See the API docs I've listed to above for full details about the **GET Folder** response.)

If you're using the Smartsheet Python SDK to issue the **GET Folder** request, then the following code may be helpful. It issues a **GET Folder** request and then iterates through objects in the response to print info about the contents of the folder.

```
folderId = 1589169626605444

# get the parent folder
parent_folder = smartsheet_client.Folders.get_folder(folderId)

# print sheet info
print('----')
print('Number of sheets: ' + str(len(parent_folder.sheets)))
for sheet in parent_folder.sheets:
    print('Sheet: ' + sheet.name)

# print folder info
print('----')
print('Number of folders: ' + str(len(parent_folder.folders)))
for folder in parent_folder.folders:
    print('Folder: ' + folder.name)

# print report info
print('----')
print('Number of reports: ' + str(len(parent_folder.reports)))
for report in parent_folder.reports:
    print('Report: ' + report.name)

# print dashboard info
print('----')
print('Number of dashboards: ' + str(len(parent_folder.sights)))
for sight in parent_folder.sights:
    print('Dashboard: ' + sight.name)
print('----')
```

For the parent folder described above, this code prints the following output to the console:

```
----
Number of sheets: 2
Sheet: Sheet 1
Sheet: Sheet 2
----
Number of folders: 2
Folder: Subfolder 1
Folder: Subfolder 2
----
Number of reports: 2
Report: Report 1
Report: Report 2
----
Number of dashboards: 2
Dashboard: Dashboard 1
Dashboard: Dashboard 2
```